# Como encontrar valores Null sem especificar atributo (MariaDB)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, null

Gostaria de fazer uma pesquisa para encontrar valores NULL em toda a tabela sem ter que determinar qual dos atributos poderá ter conter NULL.

OBS: com TODA a tabela quero dizer que em alguma parte dela possua null, não que a tabela deverá ser composta inteiramente de elementos null. OK?

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Lucas, por favor especifique qual gerenciador de banco de dados está utilizando, pois existem maneiras diferentes para fazê-lo em cada um deles. Por exemplo: Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc...

Comment: Ok desculpe, estou utilizando MariaDB, que é baseado em MySql

Answer (score 2):

Lucas, para realizar o procedimento que você deseja um tanto de trabalho manual é necessário (ou uma stored procedure, o que foge um pouco do meu conhecimento no MySQL).

Para tal você pode seguir os seguintes passos:

1) Execute o seguinte select alterando o nome da tabela (sua_tabela) para descobrir quais colunas podem receber valores nulos na tabela desejada.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'sua_tabela' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES';
```

Feito isso, substitua "colunas..." pelo resultado do primeiro select e altere novamente o nome de "sua_tabela". É necessário adicionar agora uma condição OR (OU) para cada coluna que você selecionar, seguido da condição IS NULL, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT colunas... FROM sua_tabela
WHERE coluna1 IS NULL 
OR coluna2 IS NULL
or colunaN... IS NULL
```

Não é um trabalho difícil, mas quanto mais colunas houverem e quanto mais for repetitivo este trabalho mais cansativo será de fazê-lo, portanto se for necessário executar este procedimento rotineiramente aconselho que você estude stored procedures do MySQL para que possa implementar esta rotina que te passei de forma automatizada.

Espero ter te ajudado.

Comment: entendi o que quer dizer, realmente eu precisava mesmo de uma função que retornasse os valores null encontrados aleatóriamente na tabela sem definição específica de colunas. Então verei um pouco mais sobre stored procedures para sanar minha necessidade. Obrigado